# In vb.net, I need to get a public property on pre-render and still catch a click event (Custom Server Control)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm having trouble understanding the life cycle of the page.

I have a custom server control, just a button:

```
Public Class MyButton
Inherits Button

Private Property _identity As String = Nothing

Public Property identity() As String
    Get
        Return _identity
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _identity = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub MyButton_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.Text = "Test Button"
    AddHandler Me.Click, AddressOf Me.TestClick
End Sub

Private Sub TestClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    SomeSub(identity)
    ... The problem is here.
            
End Sub

End Class
```

The "identity" public property is provided by another control on the page, and I can't get that value until the prerender, because it's dynamically generated; but when I try to use PreRender, I can't catch the click event.

So in other words, that "identity" is generated with a dynamic token, so in my view it's just a placeholder.

I've done a lot of jQuery based .ashx handler stuff, but this page life cycle stuff is confusing me!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the script manger in the .aspx page

```
<asp:scriptmanager runat="server">
</asp:scriptmanager>
      <asp:updatepanel runat="server">
        <contenttemplate>
             <asp:button runat="server" text="Button" /> // your button 
       </contenttemplate>
     </asp:updatepanel>
```

or you should add the Triggers

```
<asp:scriptmanager runat="server">
  </asp:scriptmanager>
      <asp:updatepanel id="UpdatePanel6" runat="server">
               <contenttemplate>
                <Triggers>
                     <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCertificateUpload" />
                         <asp:button runat="server" text="Button" /> // your button
                </Triggers>
              </contenttemplate>
            </asp:updatepanel>
```

make sure the Autopostback True for the check box